# Composer says Git not found

Tags: git, composer-php

When installing dependencies via `"composer install"`, I'm getting error:

> Installing doctrine/lexer (dev-master bc0e1f0)  Cloning 
>   bc0e1f0cc285127a38c6c8ea88bc5dba2fd53e94
>   [RuntimeException]
>   **Failed to clone** http://github.com/doctrine/lexer.git, **git was not 
>   found**, check that it is installed and in your PATH env.
>   'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program 
>   or batch file.

I'm not sure what to do... I don't need git.
Thanks!

Comment: install `git` for your system from https://git-scm.com/download/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Using `--prefer-dist` worked:

```
composer install --prefer-dist
```

to force `dist` part, which @ivoba mentioned; it seems default switch which uses `git` is `--prefer-source`.

Answer (score 34):

You should install git first

```
apt-get install git
```

Comment: What if I do have `git` installed and working, why would I get this error in that case?

Comment: @TheUnknownDev it could mean you're running the composer in the container (docker) which does not have the git installed

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. So I first used

```
composer install --prefer-dist
```

But it didn't work for me.

Then I used these commands and I solved my issue.

```
apt-get install zip
composer install --prefer-dist
```

This works for me. I think this will help someone.

Comment: `apt-get install zip` or `apt-get install git` ?

Comment: Installing zip allows composer to unzip a dist zipball. If you have `--prefer-dist` but no unzip command available, it will fall back to source and therefore relying on git.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem in windows and already installed git, so I fixed it just adding

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin

to my path enviroment var.

Answer (score 3):

On El Capitan on a fresh installation you first may also run into this problem although GIT is installed. After typing `sudo git --help` in the terminal you get a request to agree to the XCode licence terms. Walk through this procedure and then you are good to go. Weird stuff!

Comment: This 100% helped me in a situation, so it's a good check. I noticed the Xcode agreement warning and wasn't sure what the heck it was about!

Comment: Mac users must check for this, this solves my issue on macOS Monterey.

Answer (score 0):

You will need git, almost always with composer.

from the requirements;

> To install packages from sources instead of simple zip archives, you
>   will need git, svn or hg depending on how the package is
>   version-controlled.

best you get git :)

update:
you could also try to override the package definition, so that they will try to get zip instead:
As fake example:

```
         {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "doctrine/lexer",
                "version": "3.1.7",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "http://www.doctrine.net/files/doctrine.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                }
            }
```

https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/doc/04-schema.md#repositories-root-only

I did not test this, and i predict you end up in hell ;) when you will try to rewrite the f.e. doctrine composer.json.

Comment: "instead of simple zip archives" - I don't have anything against zips, why can't installer use that (part of requirements) :)

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion (there isn't any file that mentions lexer) and link and playing, I found a switch --prefer-dist, I'll post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
composer config repositories.data-migration-tool git https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool
```

Normally when you install git it's bin directory name is **github**
So use **github** instead of git

Now Command is as below

```
composer config repositories.data-migration-tool github https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool
```

After this run below command

composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.3.0

Comment: THX, that was the answer for me...
With one extra: even when you use **github** driver, composer uses the git driver, when you add `no-api: true`.

So for I removed the "no-api" flag and it worked without git binary