# Composer Failed to execute git status

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I am currently getting this error when I try to do a composer update.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Updating leafo/lessphp (dev-master c6cd043 => v0.3.9)
    [RuntimeException]                                             
    Failed to execute git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no
```

My require block is:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "knplabs/knp-menu": "2.0.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "leafo/lessphp": "v0.3.9",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "2.3.*",
    "jquery/jquery": "1.9.*",
    "FortAwesome/Font-Awesome": "3.2.1",
    "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "2.*"
},
```

I have no idea what the error means. I have tried to search via google but havent been able to solve my issue. I event tried to remove the package "leafo/lessphp": "v0.3.9" and run update again but even that throws the same error.

I tried to run "composer status https://github.com/leafo/lessphp.git" that gives me the error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

But I can open the link through the browser. The link was found in the composer.lock

Comment: You can always delete the whole vendor directory and run a fresh install from the lock file.

Comment: I just tried to remove the lessphp from the vendor directory. Then run a composer update. This results in composer trying to download it again but I get this error message: "Failed to clone https://github.com/leafo/lessphp.git, git was not found, check that it is installed and in your PATH env". If I write git in the console right after it responds fine. No idea whats going on. Git is in the path...

Comment: I just tried to remove the whole vendor directory. It then started downloading all my packages. Until it fails with: [RuntimeException]
Failed to clone https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu.git, git was not found, check that it is installed and in your PATH env. Strange... now its another package.

Comment: It seems to be fixed now running "composer install --prefer-dist" found here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17794382/995653 Now I dont get any errors. Very strange but the files must have been mixed-up somehow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composer says Git not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792588/composer-says-git-not-found)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be fixed now running "composer install --prefer-dist" found here [stackoverflow.com/a/17794382/995653](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17794382/995653) Now I dont get any errors. Very strange but the files must have been mixed-up somehow.

Comment: I've got the same error message when doing the update, also tried in the end with --prefer-dist and it didn't work. I guess that original message means that the folder script was in when it called git, was not really a git folder.  I'll try with deleting whole bundle

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I removed the `vendor` folder completely and ran `composer install` again. That solved the issue and the installation was completed successfully.

Answer (score 2):

On windows I installed git, and restarted windows. It works.