# Github-actions - composer fails with 'sh: git: not found'?

Tags: composer-php, github-actions

I have a wordpress plugin where i'm using composer to define my dependent libaries and github-actions to build the installable package. I plan to publish the vendors folder to a 'build' branch in github so the whole application can be installed.

My [composer.json](https://github.com/emeraldjava/bhaa_wordpress_plugin/blob/master/composer.json) file has this content and works locally

```
{
"name" : "emeraldjava/bhaa_wordpress_plugin",
"description" : "bhaa_wordpress_plugin",
"type" : "wordpress-plugin",
"require": {
    "scribu/scb-framework": "dev-master",
    "scribu/lib-posts-to-posts": "dev-master",
    "mustache/mustache": "2.12.0",
    "league/csv": "^9.1",
    "michelf/php-markdown": "^1.8"
},
```

and my github-actions [build.yml](https://github.com/emeraldjava/bhaa_wordpress_plugin/blob/master/.github/workflows/build.yml) file uses '[MilesChou/composer-action](https://github.com/MilesChou/composer-action)' to install the composer env in the docker container

```
jobs:
build:

runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - name: Checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v1
  - name: Composer install
    uses: MilesChou/composer-action/7.3@master
    with:
      args: install --no-dev
  - uses: docker://php:7.3-alpine
  - uses: docker://alpine/git:latest
```

From the build log, I can see that the zip files for these composer artifacts have been downloaded to the cache

```
36/38:  https://codeload.github.com/scribu/wp-scb-framework/legacy.zip/95b23ac342fce16bf5eb8d939ac5a361b94b104b
37/38:  https://codeload.github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/legacy.zip/a7834993ddbf4b0ed2c3b2dc1f3b1d093ef910a9
38/38:  https://codeload.github.com/scribu/wp-lib-posts-to-posts/legacy.zip/a695438e455587fa228e993d05b4431cde99af1b
Finished: success: 38, skipped: 0, failure: 0, total: 38
```

The build then failed with this 'sh: git: not found' error

```
Package operations: 5 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
- Installing scribu/scb-framework (dev-master 95b23ac): Cloning 95b23ac342
    Failed to download scribu/scb-framework from source: Failed to clone https://github.com/scribu/wp-scb-framework.git, git was not found, check that it is installed and in your PATH env.

sh: git: not found

    Now trying to download from dist
- Installing scribu/scb-framework (dev-master 95b23ac): Loading from cache
- Installing scribu/lib-posts-to-posts (dev-master a695438): Cloning a695438e45
    Failed to download scribu/lib-posts-to-posts from source: Failed to clone https://github.com/scribu/wp-lib-posts-to-posts.git, git was not found, check that it is installed and in your PATH env.

sh: git: not found

    Now trying to download from dist
- Installing scribu/lib-posts-to-posts (dev-master a695438): Loading from cache
- Installing mustache/mustache (v2.12.0): Loading from cache
- Installing michelf/php-markdown (1.8.0): Loading from cache
- Installing league/csv (9.4.1): Loading from cache
```

I'm assuming i need to ensure the docker container had git installed, but it seems odd that composer can access the legacy.zip file, so why it git needed at this stage?

### EDIT 1

I guess the quick fix here is a duplicate of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792588/composer-says-git-not-found?rq=1), and as the answer below states.

For the sake of completeness, lets assume i can't call 'composer --prefer-dist' how could i ensure the docker container has git available to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Composer uses dist (zip files) for tagged releases and source (git clone) for branches. Since you're targeting `master` branch for your dependencies, Composer tries to clone repositories first. You can override this behavior by using `--prefer-dist` switch:

```
with:
  args: install --prefer-dist --no-dev
```

> **`--prefer-dist`**: Reverse of `--prefer-source`, Composer will install from `dist` if possible. This can speed up installs substantially on build
>   servers and other use cases where you typically do not run updates of
>   the vendors. It is also a way to circumvent problems with git if you
>   do not have a proper setup.
>
> <sub>https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install-i</sub>