# git was not found in your PATH, skipping source download

Tags: composer-php

I am using laravel 9.

when I write this command `composer require bonecms/laravel-captcha`

I got error given below

```
In GitDownloader.php line 77:

git was not found in your PATH, skipping source download
```

[image: git was not found in your PATH, skipping source download]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer says Git not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792588/composer-says-git-not-found)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `--prefer-dist` for installation, Try:

```
composer install --prefer-dist
```

Alternatively you can try:

```
apt-get install git
composer install --prefer-dist
```

And then:

```
composer require bonecms/laravel-captcha
```

Answer (score 10):

Editing the php.ini and looking for the `;extension=zip` to change it with `extension=zip`. Upon removing the semi-colon (`;`), my problem was solved.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a similar error like:

```
In GitDownloader.php line 82:
                                                            
  git was not found in your PATH, skipping source download
```

Locate your php.ini configuration file.

For example `C:\xampp\php` look for the zip extension line and uncomment it (remove the semi-colon) behind it. It looks like `extension=zip`.
That's all

Answer (score 3):

One fix for me, just by installing the zip/unzip packages:

`apt-get install zip unzip`

That worked!

Comment: This worked for me inside a self-hosted runner for GitHub Actions.