Composer install fails with "Failed to execute git show-ref --head -d" in Docker container after switching branches
I am encountering an issue when running composer install inside a Docker container after switching branches in my Git repository. The error message I'm getting is:
git was not found in your PATH, skipping source download now trying to download from dist In GitDownloader.php line 246: Failed to execute git show-ref --head -d sh: 1: git: not found
Here's the sequence of steps that lead to the issue:
Switch Git branch using git checkout <branch_name>.
Open Docker container with docker exec -it <container_id> bash.
Run composer install inside the Docker container.
It seems like the Git executable is not found inside the Docker container after switching branches, causing composer install to fail.
My docker-compose.yml:
version: "3.7"

networks:
  app-network:
    name: app-network

volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
  dbdatatesting:
    driver: local

services:
  composer:
    image: composer/composer
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - "${APP_PATH_HOST:-./}:/var/www/html"
    networks:
      - app-network

  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: database
    ports:
      - ${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: project
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123456
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
      - .docker/database/entrypoint/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - app-network

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: database_testing
    ports:
      - ${FORWARD_DB_PORT_TESTING:-33071}:33071
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: project_testing
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123456
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdatatesting:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - app-network

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    ports:
      - "1025:1025"
      - "8025:8025"
    networks:
      - app-network

  node:
    image: "node:8"
    user: "${USER_MAPPING:-node}"
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    volumes:
      - ${APP_PATH_HOST:-./}:/var/www/html
    expose:
      - "8081"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ${APP_PATH_HOST:-./}:/var/www/html
      - .docker/nginx/default:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./localhost.crt:/etc/ssl/certs/localhost.crt
      - ./localhost.key:/etc/ssl/private/localhost.key
    ports:
      - "${HOST_HTTP_PORT:-80}:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    networks:
      - app-network

  php-fpm:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/myfolder/testproject/bc-php7.4-debug:latest
    user: "${USER_MAPPING:-1000:1000}"
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ${APP_PATH_HOST:-./}:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.9
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - app-network

Here are some additional details about my environment:
Operating System: Windows, subsystem Linux
Docker version: 20.10.21, build baeda1f
Composer version in docker container: 2.3.5
I hope so that there is some solution that doesn't require uninstall docker and deleting my containers, because I need to continue my work.
Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Here's what I've tried so far to troubleshoot the issue:
Restarting Docker: I've tried restarting Docker to see if the issue persists, but it didn't resolve the problem.
Tried Git installation: but still git not found in docker container.
Rebuilding Docker container: I've tried rebuilding the Docker container from scratch using the latest Docker image, but the issue still persists.

Does this answer your question? git was not found in your PATH, skipping source download

Hi, I already tried that, but I don't even have extension=zip in my php.ini

What is in your image's Dockerfile?  Anything you do in a container interactive shell will normally be lost as soon as the container exits; can you change branches on your host system, docker-compose build a new image, and run docker-compose up -d to recreate containers as needed, without ever being "inside a container"?

@DevMil I was thinking more along the lines of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74253497/5066497 where they seem to indicate that git is actually not packaged in the composer image.

@9301293 When I do in docker container, it says this :/var/www/html$ apt-get install git
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend)

I fixed it with deleting vendor folder and then again run composer install

@DevMil I’m not sure why that would work, but okay
